# Add configurations for Connectors in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

How do i add configurations for users, when they want to add my connector?

F.x. if I add the GitHub connector, I have to sign in, and then select which repository it should work using.

I cannot find any examples in the manifest for where to define these.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can preconfigure a connector for your users instead of making everyone do it for themselves?

Comment: No, i wish that people who add my connector, gets a configuration page, as they add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at [Build your own Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/connectors-dev-dashboard#build-your-own-connector) documentation. All your configurations can be added in the landing(configuration) page. Please check sample connector code given in [Microsoft Teams documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/samples/code-samples).